# Handlebars date sorting asc/desc

Tags: sorting, date, handlebars.js

;)

I have an object like this:

```
"datex": {
        "2015-11-15": {
            "0": {
                "page": 1
            },
            "1": {
                "page": 10
            }

        },
        "2015-11-19": {
            "0": {
                "page": 2
            },
            "1": {
                "page": 11
            }

        },
        "2015-11-18": {
            "0": {
                "page": 1
            },
            "1": {
                "page": 20
            }   
        }
    }
```

I use Handlebars Helper for sorting:

```
   ////// RIORDINA PER DATA
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachSorted', function(context, options) {
    var ret = "";
    Object.keys(context).sort().forEach(function(key) {
        ret = ret + options.fn({key: key, value: context[key]})
    })
    return ret
})
```

Handlebars return me correct sorting value:

```
    2015-11-15
    2015-11-18
    2015-11-19
```

But I need to reverse from big date to low date:

```
    2015-11-19
    2015-11-18
    2015-11-15
```

Thanks for Help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `registerHelper` you can provide a compare function to the sort that compares two dates:

```
var fnCompare = function(a,b) {
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b) - new Date(a);
};
Object.keys(context).sort(fnCompare).forEach(function(key) {
  ret = ret + options.fn({key: key, value: context[key]})
})
```

Comment: Thanks for help ;)

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!